# CSS trasition - Slide down and up

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying show/hide div on click, and wanted to use `CSS` transition, that will be like when clicked on open, it will show a div from top to bottom with sliding effect, and and when close it will slide up from bottom and hide, I attempt to create this using `css transition` but not working, can anybody suggest?

Here is the [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/raxc5595/4/)

```js
$('.showdiv').click(function(){
        $(".morphing_search").show();
});

$('.close-btn').click(function(){
        $(".morphing_search").hide();
});
```

```css
body {
background: #fff;
}
.morphing_search {
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
left: 0;
top: 20px;
background: #cdcdcd;
display: none;
transition-property: all;
transition-duration: .1s;
transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
}
.close-btn {
position: absolute;
right: 30px;
top: 10px;
background: #f00;
color: #fff;
padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="showdiv" href="javascript:;">Open box</a>
<div class="morphing_search"> this is the test div </div>
<a class="close-btn" href="javascript:;">X</a>
```

Comment: 1. I don't see you used any css animation. 2. Why don't you use `slideToggle()` in jQuery?

Comment: I've used transition and wanted to handle it with css only

Comment: I got this transition from here: https://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-slide.php

Comment: Why not using `fadeIn()` / `fadeOut()` instead of `hide` and `show`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use display property when using animation/transition in css.

So, what I did is I animate the max-height.

In active state, I exaggerated the value.

```js
$('.showdiv').click(function(){
   $(".morphing_search").addClass('active');
});

$('.close-btn').click(function(){
   $(".morphing_search").removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.morphing_search {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  left: 0;
  top: 20px;
  background: #cdcdcd;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: .7s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
}

.morphing_search.active {
  max-height: 500px; }

.close-btn {
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 10px;
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="showdiv" href="javascript:;">Open box</a>
<div class="morphing_search"> this is the test div </div>
<a class="close-btn" href="javascript:;">X</a>
```

Using css. You need to add and remove class.

Hope it helps! Cheers!

Comment: To clarify, in order to have the feature open from top to bottom and close from bottom to top, you need to add the keyword "height" in the transition timing function, specifically: height cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);

Comment: @user3200950 max-height handles everything, you cannot animate height property in css. :)